# Raspberry Pi - Run Python script at Startup using "screen" session

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, startup

I have really tried looking around but all the examples I find do not work for me.

I have a **python script** in a Raspberry Pi that starts using **CRON**....all good!

I would like to be able to debug the ouput that the script prints in screen from time to time so the "screen" command needs to be used to **create a session** and ensure that I can login and logoff using putty as needed.

I also add the "&" so it will run in background.

**So currently I did:**

1) Open cron

```
sudo crontab -e
```

2) Add the following line

```
@reboot python /home/pi/python/monitor.py &
```

This works correctly, I just need to know how to make a "screen" session open before launching the python script.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what? wouldnt you just write it to a logfile?

Comment: That would limit the SD card life, and I dont need logs that bad. Just a quick check from time to time on screen.

Comment: Im pretty sure you cannot do that ... when you login via putty or whatever then you are in a different session which would not see the output from the other session that is running your script (granted I could be wrong ... Im by no means a linux guru) although this might do what you want http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58601

Comment: Redirect output to a logfile on a tmpfs.

Comment: So, I guess what I wanted to do specifically can not be done.